# Hotmail email attatchment limit

Tags: email, attachments, hotmail

I am trying to send a email with an attachment that is 10.2MB.  The receiver has not received it.  I am using Microsoft Outlook, which has Hotmail configured.  I have done some research and I am finding conflicting answers:

1) The total size of all attachments must not exceed 10GB.
2) The total size of all attachments must not exceed 5GB.
3) The total size of a single attachment must not exceed 10GB.  The total size of all attachments must not exceed 25GB

I have found more statements.  Which one is it?

This link makes it even more confusing: https://www.outlook-apps.com/maximum-email-size/.  What is I have outlook configured in Outlook (Outlook installed on local PC)? Is the limit 10MB or 20MB?

Comment: The limit is based on your subscription tier.  The link you provided us isn't a Microsoft link.  It's also extremely outdated

Answer (score 0):

I logged in to my mail account here and sent the email: https://outlook.live.com/owa/?authRedirect=true.  This removed Microsoft Outlook from the equation and the email sent successfully.  The Hotmail limit for an attachment is: 30MB.